# System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl in VS2008 project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-controls

I have created a website project in VS2008 and in the appcode folder I have created a class deriving from System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl. I need to use this control in one of my webforms. I can't figure out how to.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this example: [Creating and Using User Control Libraries](http://webproject.scottgu.com/VisualBasic/UserControls/UserControls.aspx)

What you want to accomplish is:

[image: Resized image from Scott Gu's site to fit StackOverflow.comt]

Where you have a Register directive to provide a link to the control's ascx source page and providing a TagPrefix and TagName to reference the control in the page. In addition, you could also set any properties you have provided for the user control if you have.

If this is just a user control you want to reference from an assembly Check this link out: [Giving a .NET Assembly a Strong Name](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/experts/article.php/c4643)